# Object Assign and object instances

Tags: node.js

In this Express route, I import this perspectives module.

```
//routes/api.js
var perspectives = require('../controllers/perspectives');
router.route('/perspectives/newsletter')
      .post(function(req, res){
      var p = perspectives.setNewsletterHttpRequest(req);
      p.updateNewsletter();
});
```

The setNewsletterHttpRequest(req) method takes the request object and then returns a copy (Object.assign) of the perspectives module itself.

```
//controllers/perspectives.js
perspectives.setNewsletterHttpRequest = function(req, updateMarketoOnly) {
    let user = req.body.users[0];
    this.validBpNewsletterUpdateInput = true;
    this.user = user;

    return Object.assign({},this);
}

module.exports = perspectives;
```

Does returning this module via Object.assign in setNewsletterHttpRequest keep the object isolated so that each request creates its own instance of a perspectives object (each with its own user values set via the http request req.body.users[0] line)? I'm trying to ensure that there isn't any way for different requests to modify the same object but that each request is modifying the state for its own instance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) copies from a source object to a target object, so each object will be separate from all the others in your case. HOWEVER....

If any of the property values are objects (including, for example, arrays), they will be copied by reference. (That may not be technically correct, but it's adequate shorthand for this situation.) Sooooo:

```
var source = {num:0, str:'', arr:[], obj:{}}; 
var a = Object.assign({}, source);
var b = Object.assign({}, source);
console.log(a === b); //false
console.log(a == b); //false

// Let's modify `b` and see what happens.
b.added = 'I added this';
console.log(a.added); //undefined, cool

b.num = 4;
console.log(a.num); //0, cool

b.arr.push('new value');
console.log(a.arr) //['new value'], wha??!!!

b.obj.newValue = 'new value';
console.log(a.obj) //{newValue: 'new value'}, also wha???!!!!
```

So, yes, the resulting objects are different objects, but be careful because it's a shallow copy!

Comment: Thanks. So I am only using primitives on the user object, which should be okay then. But if an object is used as a property, then there could be problems, as your example shows. This leads to another question, since each object returned from setNewsletterHttpRequest is generated by an http request via an Express route, shouldn't each request be isolated - meaning that there is only one  var p = perspectives.setNewsletterHttpRequest(req) executing at any given time (each with its own properties set via the request body)?